# Acumatica - Failed to convert parameter value from a PXResultset`1 to a String

Tags: acumatica

We are having to call a stored procedure within a foreach loop of the ARTran records to update a different set of ARTran records based on 2 values from the original recordset of ARTran records.  Our code validated and published but we are getting the following error when we click Process.

```
1/9/2018 10:52:52 AM Error: 
Failed to convert parameter value from a PXResultset`1 to a String. 

System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible. 
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, 
IFormatProvider provider) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, 
MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& 
typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, 
MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& 
typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean 
isCommandProc) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, 
Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, 
SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior 
cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean 
async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, 
SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior 
cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String 
method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, 
Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) 
at
```

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSou
    rce`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, 
    Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) 
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    at PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.Execute(String procedureName, 
    PXSPParameter[] pars) 
    at PX.Data.PXDatabase.Execute(String procedureName, PXSPParameter[] 
    pars) 
    at DocCenter.UpdateLastNotified.b__0() 
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0()

Here is the code that we have for the processing.  Can anyone advise me on what the issue is here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Data;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.IN;


namespace DocCenter
{
  public class UpdateLastNotified : PXGraph<UpdateLastNotified>
  {
    public PXFilter<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> MasterView;
    public PXCancel<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> Cancel;

[PXFilterable]




    public PXSelectJoin<ARTran, 
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<ARTran.inventoryID, Equal <InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,
  InnerJoin<ARInvoice, On<ARTran.refNbr, Equal <ARInvoice.refNbr>>,  
  InnerJoin<ItemBaseDocument, On<InventoryItemExt.usrDocumentNumber, Equal<ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode>>,
  InnerJoin<Contact, On<ARTranExt.usrContactID, Equal<Contact.contactID>>>>>>,  
  Where<ARTranExt.usrDateNotified, Less<ItemBaseDocument.revisionDateReceived>>> DetailsView;

 public UpdateLastNotified() 
    {
   Cancel.SetCaption("Clear Filter");
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowDelete = false;
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowUpdate = true; 
    }


protected virtual IEnumerable detailsView()
{
UpdateLastNotifiedFilter filter = MasterView.Current as UpdateLastNotifiedFilter;
PXSelectBase<ARTran> cmd = new PXSelectJoin<ARTran, 
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<ARTran.inventoryID, Equal <InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,
  InnerJoin<ARInvoice, On<ARTran.refNbr, Equal <ARInvoice.refNbr>>,  
  InnerJoin<ItemBaseDocument, On<InventoryItemExt.usrDocumentNumber, Equal<ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode>>,
  InnerJoin<Contact, On<ARTranExt.usrContactID, Equal<Contact.contactID>>>>>>,  
  Where<ARTranExt.usrDateNotified, Less<ItemBaseDocument.revisionDateReceived>>>(this);    

   return cmd.Select();
}



public PXAction<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> Process;
[PXProcessButton]
[PXButton(CommitChanges=true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Process")]
protected virtual IEnumerable process(PXAdapter adapter)
{

  PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate() 
  {
  foreach(ARTran tran in DetailsView.Select())
    {
    if (tran.Selected==true)
      {

      ARTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<ARTranExt>();
      ARInvoiceEntry tranEntry = new ARInvoiceEntry();
      tranExt.UsrDateNotified = MasterView.Current.DateNotified;
      tranEntry.Transactions.Update(tran);
      tranEntry.Save.PressButton();

      int? companyid = PX.Common.PXContext.GetSlot<Int32?>("singleCompanyID");


      var sp_MySP_Parms = new PXSPParameter[4];

      PXSPParameter p1 = new PXSPInParameter("@I_vBaseDocumentCode", PXDbType.NChar, DetailsView.Select("BaseDocumentCode"));
      PXSPParameter p2 = new PXSPInParameter("@I_vEmail", PXDbType.NChar, DetailsView.Select("EMail"));
      PXSPParameter p3 = new PXSPInParameter("@I_vCompanyID", PXDbType.Int, companyid);
      PXSPParameter p4 = new PXSPInParameter("@I_vDateNotified", PXDbType.DateTime, MasterView.Current.DateNotified);

      sp_MySP_Parms[0] = p1;
      sp_MySP_Parms[1] = p2;
      sp_MySP_Parms[2] = p3;
      sp_MySP_Parms[3] = p4;

      object[] ret = PXDatabase.Execute("icanUpdateDateLastNotifiedForBaseDocumentAndEmail", sp_MySP_Parms);

      }

    }


  }

        );
 return adapter.Get();
}

    [Serializable]
    public class UpdateLastNotifiedFilter : IBqlTable
    {

      #region DateNotified
      public abstract class dateNotified : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      } 
      [PXDBDate()]
      [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date Notified")]
      public DateTime? DateNotified { get; set; }
      #endregion 

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From the traces I think it fails when SQL client tries to convert the DateTime? stored proc input parameter value to a string in order to compose the SQL query string. At the very least we know that it tries to convert a variable of type object to string using the IConvertible interface. Could it be that you have to pass a DateTime parameter instead of  a nullable DateTime? MasterView.Current.DateNotified.Value

Comment: I can see MasterView.Current.DateNotified being of value null. The parameter is of type object so null is valid but it can't be converted to string because a null object reference lacks the IConvertible interface. If the error is not related to '@I_vDateNotified', it could be related to the other stored proc input param.

Comment: MasterView.Current.DateNotified should not have a value of null.  There is a date selected in that field on the screen.

Comment: I tried to set the DateNotified value to string with the following:

Comment: PXSPParameter p4 = new PXSPInParameter("@I_vDateNotified", 
     PXDbType.NChar, MasterView.Current.DateNotified.ToString("yyyy-
     MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
      
      sp_MySP_Parms[0] = p1;
      sp_MySP_Parms[1] = p2;
      sp_MySP_Parms[2] = p3;
      sp_MySP_Parms[3] = p4;
      
      object[] ret = 
 PXDatabase.Execute("icanUpdateDateLastNotifiedForBaseDocumentAn
     dEmail", sp_MySP_Parms);

Comment: Getting the following error:

Comment: \App_RuntimeCode\UpdateLastNotified.cs(85): error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
\App_RuntimeCode\UpdateLastNotified.cs(85): error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Can you check if the number of parameters is correct with the ToString call "DateNotified.ToString". DateNotified should be DateTime? because all DAC fields need to be nullable. So you need to set it to DateTime? in the DAC and do DateNotified.Value.ToString([...]), You shouldn't call ToString on a nullable object, you have to extract the Value from the nullable type and call ToString on that.

Comment: Also you have changed the code since you posted the question. Error on Line 85 doesn't match Line 85 from your question source code anymore. Can you tell me what is currently on Line 85 and make sure error still happens on Line 85. Also if possible the exception Stack Trace of that error.